# vectorized version of a formula

Tags: matlab, vectorization, convolution

I want to write a vectorized version of this formula :

[image: formula]

The sum goes from `1` to `j` and from `1` to `k`.

I wrote this version with loops:

```
function [ F] = calculation( A,B)
    C=zeros(size(A)+2);
    for j=1:size(C,1)
        for k=1:size(C,2)
            for p=1:j
                for q=1:k
                    C(j,k)=C(j,k)+A(p,q)*B(j-p+1,k-q+1);
                end
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Can you help me to vectorize it ?

As you will notice, it's the formula of `conv2`. This function will show for the syntax `F=conv2(A,B)` an output `F` with a size : `size(F)=size(A)+size(B)-1;` .

My second question is if there is a way to calculate the convolution but only for the region `F(1:size(A,1)+2,1:size(A,2)+2)` and without calculating the other components (to speed up the calculations) ?

Comment: Why do you not use `conv2`? What have you tried so far to vectorise your calculation?

Comment: Just use conv2 and crop the output.

Comment: Note also that conv2 is a built-in function so it's going to be faster nonetheless of whether you'll be able to fully optimize your code.